# aiohttp и asyncio

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Доброго времени суток всем! Есть примерно такой код:

```
import aiohttp



def handle(request):
    pass


async def main():
    pass 


app = aiohttp.web.Application()
app.router.add_post('/', handle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    aiohttp.web.run_app(app)
```

Могу ли я паралельно c `aiohttp.web.run_app(app)` выполнять асинхронную функцию `main()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - запустить таск. Но внутри `main` должен `await` на каждой итерации (если это цикл) или хотяб `await asyncio.sleep(0)` между тяжелыми кусками, а блокирующие операции вынесенны в экзекутор:

```
import aiohttp
def handle(request):
    pass
async def main():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('.') 
app = aiohttp.web.Application()
app.router.add_post('/', handle)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    aiohttp.web.run_app(app)
```

Второй вариант - вынести aiohttp в runner

```
async def run():
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, '0.0.0.0', 8080)
    await site.start()
    return await main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Comment: Все равно main() выполняется только один раз. Сделал все как ты написал.

Comment: А сколько раз нужно?

Comment: Функция main() должна работать постоянно. В функции есть цикл который постоянно повторяется и также в функции присутствуют await

Comment: у меня код с 4мя вечными циклами стрим сервером и аиохттп работает нормально. добавь код - посмотрю что ещё не хватает

Comment: Все работает!!! Спасибо большое.

Comment: @self_taught галочку на ответе можно поставить